# printing a wchar_t in visual studio and eclipse gives different results

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, cross-platform

I am using eclipse and Visual Studio on a windows x64. When I print the following string in visual studio by incrementing the pointer by 1, it displays correct result in visual studio. But in eclipse the pointer is advanced by 4 instead of by 1. Why this difference? How can make the pointer advance by 1 in eclipse too ?

**INPUT STRING**

[{"scaleFactor":4,"ball":{"radius":0.03999999910593033}}]

**CODE**

```
unsigned char* temp = fileUtils->getFileData("levels.json", "r", &size);
wchar_t *levelData  = new wchar_t[size];
size_t len_or_error = 0;
if(size > 0) {
    const char* temp1 = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(temp);
    len_or_error = mbstowcs(&levelData[0], &temp1[0], size);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    CCLOG("i = %d | %s ", i, levelData + i);
}
```

**OUTPUT VS 12**

```
i = 0 | [
i = 1 | { 
i = 2 | " 
i = 3 | s 
i = 4 | c 
i = 5 | a 
i = 6 | l
```

**OUTPUT ECLIPSE**

```
i = 0 | [{"scaleFactor":4,"ball":{"radius":0.03999999910593033}}]
i = 1 | caleFactor":4,"ball":{"radius":0.03999999910593033}}]
i = 2 | Factor":4,"ball":{"radius":0.03999999910593033}}]
i = 3 | or":4,"ball":{"radius":0.03999999910593033}}]
i = 4 | 4,"ball":{"radius":0.03999999910593033}}]
```

**UPDATE**
Forgot to mention that Im running the eclipse version on an android device and not on windows itself.

**UPDATE2**

Added extra code before printing the wchar_t .

CCLOG is the default logger for cocos2d-x https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x

Comment: The size of `wchar_t` is not guaranteed to be 16 bits.

Comment: I feel that Eclipse is doing (more of) the right thing, if you are using %s as the format specifier - you are printing a string... You need to show us a little more of the code that prints the data (for example what type `levelData` is.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    CCLOG("i = %d | %c ", i, temp + i);
}

Comment: @neagoegab That did not work in android. It printed garbage values. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that `wchar_t` is a different size with the VC++ compiler compared to other compilers, such as GCC.

Windows uses [two bytes to represent wchar_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376812/wchar-t-is-2-bytes-in-visual-studio-and-stores-utf-16-how-do-unicode-aware-appl).  Your code appears to work correctly on in Visual Studio because you tell the format string specifier to read a narrow string (one byte).  Instead of `%s` you should use `%ls` to correctly read a wide string.  However, I think what you actually want to do is read a single character.  To do this try:

```
printf("i = %d | %lc\r\n ", i, *( levelData + i ) );
```

You don't specify what compiler you're using with Eclipse, but GCC (and I think MinGW) use up to 4 bytes for storing `wchar_t` and that is why it is jumping by 4 bytes.  See [How big is wchar_t with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873565/how-big-is-wchar-t-with-gcc) It also looks like it is using a variable length encoding to store the data.